# how to write angularjs directive to dynamically allocate scope bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is there a way to specify the scope bindings of a particular element through a directive?

eg:

```
<div g:bind="{width: '=', height: '@'}" width="myWidth" height={{myHeight}}></div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a more elaborate example of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so.  I believe that when you define the object hash (i.e., the stuff inside `scope: { ... }`), you must use strings as the keys -- you can't "look them up" elsewhere.

```
scope: { stringKey1: ..., stringKey2: ... }
```

AFAIK, only the compile() and link() functions get an [Attributes](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile.directive.Attributes) object.  You would need that object to do what you want, but you don't have it when the "directive definition object" is being parsed.